# Dapper: Throw error on failed mapping

Tags: dapper

Is there an option to have dapper throw an error if the Query method fails to find a property matching a returned column in a result set?
For example:

```
public class Person{
  public String FirstName {get; set;}
  public String LastName {get; set;}
}
...
conn.Query<Person>("select FName, LName from Users");
```

The above would throw no error despite that no data was transferred due to the name mismatch.

If not is there a reason not to add it?  My old home-grown micro-ORM did this and I miss the feature so I'd consider attempting to add it, but not if there were specific design decisions that already eliminated it (ie "raw performance").

Comment: There is currently no option to do this in Dapper. The feature request is here: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/254

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a chunk of code called SafeDapper:

https://github.com/LarrySmith-1437/SafeDapper

Answer (score -1):

Different naming property you must be manual mapping.

Install [Dapper.FluentMap NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.FluentMap).

Manual mapping

```
public class PersonMap : EntityMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        // Map property 'FirstName' to column 'FName'.
        Map(p => p.FirstName)
            .ToColumn("FName");

        // Map property 'FirstName' to column 'FName'.
        Map(p => p.LastName)
            .ToColumn("LName");
    }
}
```

**Initialization:**

```
FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
                       {
                           config.AddMap(new PersonMap());
                       });
```

Comment: I don't want to make it work, I want it to throw an exception so I know to update the query.